# Bash command sometimes runs with spinner in background and not sure why

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I am creating a faster workflow for working with a BigCommerce (Spotify competitor) theme and found [this basic release tool](https://github.com/release-it/release-it) which had a lot of stars and seemed light and simple. I wanted to in one command run tests, create a release (with all the trimmings in the /release tabs in my GitHub repo for the theme) and use BigCommerce's tools to update the ecom store with the latest theme.

The `release-it` tool I linked above has a spot in it's config where it will fire a specified command after it's done with the release. BigCommerce has a tool called [stencil](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs) that has a simple one-line command `stencil push` to upload and publish on the site. All this works fine as separate steps but I'm trying to just make it one button.

**Question**: When `release-it` finishes and executes `stencil-push` it looks like the following picture below - the command fires next to a spinner (not sure if this is builtin to the terminal or not) and sits there.

[image]

When this command is ran normally it is interactive, outputting stuff, and ultimately needs a `y/N` response to confirm the upload, which I cannot do as it spins with no output or input taken.

I am not sure what is happening here, if `release-it` is executing the command in a way I'm unfamiliar with. Two things I've tried are changing the command to `. stencil push` or `source stencil push`, and putting the whole command into an executable shell script, and telling `release-it` to execute this. Same result.

Thanks for any help figuring out my issue.

Comment: Does the Stencil tool have a non-interactive mode you can use? CI tools cannot generally accept input in an interactive manner, so it's probably getting stuck at the Y/N prompt. You could run `release-it -VV` to get more information on what's happening.

Comment: @Haxiel it's definitely getting stuck at the prompt. Do you know if that spinner is a normal built in thing that appears when a script is, say, forced to run in the background or a different process?

Comment: According to [this GIF](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/release-it/release-it/master/docs/assets/release-it.gif), the spinner seems to be part of the release-it tool. Different programs have different progress indicators, and some don't even have them. It's definitely not a standard, but there's nothing special about the spinner itself.

Comment: @Haxiel thank you for your responses and your time. I agree with you, this appears part of the release-it tool. I have completed a workaround that simply makes a new script which calls `release-it` and once that completes successfully, `stencil push` is then called. I am still curious to learn about what might be happening, do you know if it would be possible for release-it to takes a command and force it into this state? where it is suppressing stdout from the command line and just wrapping it in a spinner? How would it potentially go about doing that?

Comment: I think it's a simple matter of redirection. `stencil push </dev/null` should exhibit the same behaviour. Here, we're overriding the standard input (from the keyboard) with the null file, so the program cannot accept interactive input. Output and error can be redirected the same way. CI tools generally collect the output and error streams to a file, so that they can be looked at later on.

Comment: For the spinner, [you can take a look at the code directly](https://github.com/release-it/release-it/blob/master/lib/spinner.js). I'm not very familiar with JS, but the code seems to initializing a spinner with a corresponding task, and then simply waiting for the task to finish.

Comment: `stencil push </dev/null` would still output stuff I believe, which this does not, but I think part of your point is that stdout could also be redirected somewhere. Seems strange that the authors of release-it would choose this, maybe they want a clean and clear terminal output. You nailed it with the spinner tho - here is the package that file you linked imports that does this exact thing https://www.npmjs.com/package/ora

Thanks again so much for your knowledge and helping me learn

Comment: I'm glad to help someone who is genuinely willing to learn :-). Since this is a Q&A site, would you consider adding your workaround as a self-answer to this question? This would be useful to a future reader, and would be generally valuable for the site. Comments are supposed to be temporary, so they end up being removed at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `release-it` tool executes the command in a non-interactive mode without stdin or stdout available. My workaround (for future readers who find this post with a similar issue) was to build a simple shell script above `release-it`, which calls `release-it` and after successful completion, then calls `stencil push`